# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed on api level 28 and 29 with using okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

Hi I am writing an android app that use okhttp to connect to server, I was ok with api levels below 28 for connecting and fetch data from server but in phones that have android 28 and greater I got failed to connect to server error. 
My first code was :

```
private void getToken(){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    cons.phoneNumber = dbHelper.readUserMobile(api.getDatabase());
    Log.i("Log40","phone in OkHttp is: "+ cons.phoneNumber);
    Request request = api.loginRequest(cons.phoneNumber);
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            //my codes on failure
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
           //my codes for response 
        }
    });

}
```

and my api.loginRequest(cons.phoneNumber) function was:

```
public Request loginRequest(String phoneNumber){
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Grant_Type","password")
            .add("username",phoneNumber)
            .build();
    //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "Grant_Type=password&username="+phoneNumber);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://"siteadress"/api/v1/User/Login")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "Pouya")
            .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Host", "hostip:hostport")
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .addHeader("Content-Length", "40")
            .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();
    return request;
}
```

but when doing it i got Failed to connect to server error : CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client

so I searched the web and stack overflow they said that problem was about missing ***s*** after ***http***  problem so I added ***s*** but i got new error and error is :

**Failed to connect to to server, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed**

I have read the stack flow again and searched and my code changed to this :

```
private void getToken(){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS))
            .build();
    java.lang.System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
    cons.phoneNumber = dbHelper.readUserMobile(api.getDatabase());
    Log.i("Log40","phone in OkHttp is: "+ cons.phoneNumber);
    Request request = api.loginRequest(cons.phoneNumber);
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            //my codes on failure
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
           //my codes for response 
        }
    });

}
```

and added **s** to http address in my api.loginRequest(cons.phoneNumber) function but I still get the **Failed to connect to to server, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed** error. does anyone can help ?

Comment: "so I searched the web and stack overflow they said that problem was about missing s after http problem" -- you also need to configure your Web server to support HTTPS requests. Is it?

Comment: I think so ... how can I find that out ?

Comment: Ask whoever is maintaining that server.

Comment: I asked him and he said yes it's support it :(

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to accomplish with the `System.setProperty()` call. In fact, I would just take that out. Please add the entire stack trace. It likely includes information particular to the precise cause of the failure.